# Son has a new MacBook air and I'd like to track messages

Tags: messages

My son has a new MacBook Air and uses Messages to text friends etc. 
I have found some disturbing texts on his computer and would like to track them and watch them.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have his Apple ID and password?  The only way to do this would be to use his credentials to login from a different computer.  Does he only send messages via the MBA and not an iPhone?

Comment: Do you have physical access to this Mac including the user password? Also, from an ethical standpoint, you should let your son know that you are monitoring his messages, even if he is not an adult.

Comment: There's no way to do it covertly anyway. If you read a message, it will be marked as read on all associated devices.

Comment: Close voters:  This question is very much on topic as it has to do with managing the use of a MacBook

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to get his Apple ID Password and setup iMessages with his account on your phone or computer.

You will be able to see all the iMessages he sends and receives.

The hard part could be getting his Apple ID password, and even once you get it he could always change the password, which would sign out of his account.

Answer (score 0):

You need monitoring software such as [WebWatcher](https://www.webwatcher.com/mac-monitoring).

We used to recommend this type of software to parents who wanted to monitor their child's behavior while online.  The caveat is you will need access to the device to install the software which will run covertly on the system.

Since the IT department had access to any and all laptops that were on the network, we were more than willing to assist parents in policing their child's online activities.  If this MacBook Air is school issued, you may be able to get some assistance from their IT department.